# Reactjs: handleScroll function not work when the state has length

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when the server is stoped, my component can't fetch data, and this time, if I scroll the page, **handleScroll** function works. but if i run server, my component fetch data and set the data to state. and if the state has length, **handleScroll** function don't work.

my code:

```
//...existing code
this.state={
            status:[],
            pageNumber: 1,
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        let store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login'))
        var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapi/allpost/?format=json&page='+this.state.pageNumber
        fetch(url,{
            method:'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Token '+store.token
            }
        })
        .then(res=>res.json().then(result=>{
            this.setState({status: result.results, pageNumber:this.state.pageNumber+1})
            
        }))
    }
//...code
handleScroll=(event)=>{
        console.log('scrolling')//<-- even it don't work when state.status has length
        const bottom = event.target.scrollHeight - event.target.scrollTop === event.target.clientHeight;
        if(bottom){
            console.log('bottom')
        }
    }
    render() {
        if(Object.keys(this.state.status).length){
            //..code
            })
            return (
                <div><br/>
                <div style={{overflowY:'scroll', height:'92vh'}} className='hide-scrollbar'>
                    
                    <div id="scroll" onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
                       Received data from api. but handleScroll function don't work.
                       <p>...more code...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            );
        }else {
            return (
                <div onScroll={this.handleScroll} style={{overflowY:'scroll', height:'92vh'}}>
                <div>
                <br/>
                    <p style={{textAlign:'center'}}>loading...</p>
                    <p>handleScroll function works</p>
                    <p>...more code...</p>
                    
                </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}

export default Home2;
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Maybe because when there is a valid state , you `div` on which you added `handleScroll` is actually not scrollable due to lack of `overflow-y` and a **fixed-height** ? It's on the parent div in this case and not on that div itself. While in your other-case your style is on the same div where your `handleScroll` is attached.

Comment: Thank you sir. I found the solution. 